# Adding viewport tag to header.php causes php error

Tags: php, viewport

I am using a php script that has a file header.php with the normal web page header info. However, when I add the viewport tag it throws an error.

header.php:

```
<?php
/*
UserCake Version: 2.0.2
http://usercake.com
*/
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>  
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>".$websiteName."</title>
<link href='".$template."' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src='models/funcs.js' type='text/javascript'>
</script>
</head>";

?>
```

Error returned:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/30/d332080598/htdocs/azotusorg/usercake/models/header.php on line 10
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping double quotes here

```
<?php
echo "
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
 <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
 <head>
 <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/>  
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
 <title>".$websiteName."</title>
 <link href='".$template."' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <script src='models/funcs.js' type='text/javascript'>
 </script>
 </head>";
?>
```

**OR** use single quotes

```
<?php
echo "
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
 <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
 <head>
 <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>  
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
 <title>".$websiteName."</title>
 <link href='".$template."' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <script src='models/funcs.js' type='text/javascript'>
 </script>
 </head>";
?>
```